# Swift upload file via WCF

Tags: swift, vb.net, rest, wcf

I've been fighting this for over 10 hours and done my best before coming here. Many tutorials I've looked out ended up being outdated by a version or two and/or missing some key knowledge in the explanation.

I'm trying to upload a PDF to a server using a WCF Rest Service. When I debug on the WCF service, the variable named document is a null stream. I've searched the web many hours trying many different things and I've exhausted MANY attempts to get such a little thing to work! What is really annoying is that this isn't the first time someone has needed to do this and yet I haven't found an answer anywhere.

If there is a better way to post the PDF other than what I've posted, I'm open to suggestions but I don't want to use third-party frameworks.

Requirements:
 - Using the WCF service is required
 - I'm not saving to a file system or UNC

I need to get a valid memory stream passed to the service and I can take care of the function code from there. I've tried using a Base64DataString before this and I could get that to work either. If you wanted to provide that as an option, I'm open to it.

Please help!

Swift 4 code:

import PDFKit

```
class FileUpload {

    static func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
        return "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
    }

    static func dataUploadBodyWithParameters(_ parameters: [String: Any]?, filename: String, mimetype: String, dataKey: String, data: Data, boundary: String) -> Data {
        var body = Data()
        // encode parameters first
        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(dataKey)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(data)
        body.appendString("\r\n")
        body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
        print(body)
        return body
    }

    static func uploadData(_ data: Data, toURL urlString: String, withFileKey fileKey: String, completion: ((_ success: Bool, _ result: Any?) -> Void)?) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            // build request
            let boundary = generateBoundaryString()
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)

            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

            // build body
            let body = dataUploadBodyWithParameters(nil, filename: "iOSUpload.pdf", mimetype: "application/pdf", dataKey: fileKey, data: data, boundary: boundary)
            request.httpBody = body

            //UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if data != nil && error == nil {
                    do {
                        let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                        print(result)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { completion?(true, result) })
                    } catch {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { completion?(false, nil) })
                    }
                } else { DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { completion?(false, nil) }) }
                //UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            }).resume()
        } else { DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { completion?(false, nil) }) }
    }

}

extension Data {
    mutating func appendString(_ string: String) {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        append(data!)
    }
}
```

}

WCF Relevant Code:

```
<ServiceContract>
Public Interface IWebService

<OperationContract>
    <WebInvoke(Method:="POST", UriTemplate:="UploadFile/{fileName}")>
    Function UploadFile(fileName As String, document As Stream) As String

End Interface

<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.Single)>
Public Class MyWebService : Implements IWebService

Public Function UploadFile(fileName As String, document As Stream) As String Implements IWebService.UploadFile
        'document is null
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not good at WCF configuration. So, please tell me if your WCF Rest service really accepts `multipart/form-data`? Have you confirmed that using some tool like Postman?

Comment: I can probably take the multipart /form-data out. That part was from a tutorial.